# Receiving a URL Parameter in Vert.x Implementation of SockJS

Tags: java, websocket, vert.x, sockjs

We have a usecase where we need to pass a parameter, either in URL, Form Data, or headers when we're creating a SockJS connection.

We're planning to use Vert.x on Server side, and started exploring Vert.x using the [Demo](http://vertx.io/blog/real-time-bidding-with-websockets-and-vert-x/).

We modified the [Vertical](https://github.com/mwarc/simple-realtime-auctions-vertx3-example/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/mwarc/realtimeauctions/AuctionServiceVerticle.java) from [code](https://github.com/mwarc/simple-realtime-auctions-vertx3-example) and are doing following

```
            if (event.type() == BridgeEventType.SOCKET_CREATED) {
            logger.info("A socket was created");
            SockJSSocket socket = event.socket();

            logger.info(event.type());
            logger.info("socket.uri() : " + socket.uri());
            for(Entry<String, String> e : socket.headers().entries()) {
                logger.info(e.getKey() + " : " + e.getValue());
            }
        }
```

Intention being to try to pass parameter as URL encoded argument or header value.

We have tried appending param to Server URL like so

```
this.sockJSConn = new SockJS(url + "/?param=13242", null, options);
```

and passing it as options hash as suggested in [SockJS Client API Doc](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client#sockjs-class) like so

```
options['sessionId'] = 13323;
this.sockJSConn = new SockJS(url, null, options);
```

So far, we have not been able to receive this parameter on the server side.

Any ideas?

Based on the digging around we have done so far, it seems that the method above is called after the HTTP Upgrade call is made from client side, and this call does not have all the params we passed when we created the JS client.

Comment: Did you ever come up with a solution for this?